# svg.path picture not working with Russian in polyglossia

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, polyglossia, svg

I'm not sure exactly how to frame this question as I'm myself not sure what the problem is, but essentially I'm trying to draw paths using the `svg.path` TikZ library. When I select Ukrainian with `polyglossia`, it works fine. However, when I select Russian, it gives me an error.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{CMU Serif}[Script=Cyrillic]

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

% Change this to "russian" for the error
\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw svg "M 55.082,20.537 C 58.777,25.523 60.966,31.694 60.966,38.377 C 60.966,44.998 58.815,51.115 55.178,56.076";
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Error:**

```
Package pgf Error: Unexpected character 'macro:->\active@prefix
"\normal@char" ' in parser 'svgpath' in state 'initial'.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

Comment: Russian makes `"` active, so `\draw svg "...";` does not work. But `\draw svg {...};` does work. Tested with TL17 and lualatex. (I did not knwo you could use `\draw svg "...";` I've always used the `{...};` syntax.

Comment: You're right. This happens with German as well. You can make this an answer!

Comment: Maybe add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz}`. Might also have to delete the `.aux` file and recompile.

Comment: @MarkWibrow that also does work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Russian babel/polyglossia makes `"` active.

Either use

```
\draw svg {...};
```

Or as Mark Wibrow mentions in a comment, try

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

after loading `tikz`